# running coded UI automation test multiple times

Tags: .net, automated-tests, coded-ui-tests

i have created an automated testing using coded UI automation(by recording actions). i need to run the test multiple times using data driven test, connection string to XML document.
this needs to be run based on a number i give as input, this number needs to be incremented each time. is this possible in coded UI automation testing? any other suggestions?

Comment: Please clarify. You have a Coded UI test data driven from an XML file. Where does the "_number i give as input_" come from and what does it need to do for the test? To get a number that increments for each data driven execution of a test you could use a `static int` in the class. You can get the data source's row number from `int dataRowNumber = TestContext.DataRow.Table.Rows.IndexOf(TestContext.DataRow);`

Comment: i give the number input from the xml. the number is served as an input for registration purpose such as ticket number.

Comment: Still do not understand the question. If you are asking how to write a date driven test that uses an XML data source then Schaliasos's answer provides a good start. What is the number? Is it a field in the XML and if yes then what do you mean by "_this number needs to be incremented each time_"?

Answer (score 1):

All you need is to create a [CodedUI Data-driven Test](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee624082.aspx).

In the `DataSource` attribut set the `DataAccessMethod` as `DataAccessMethod.Sequential` so your test will read all data rows and execute them in the their order one at the time.

You also need to use the `DeploymentAttribute` so your xml file will be deployed to the output folder.

**Example:**

```
[DeploymentItem("data.xml")]
[DataSource("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataSource.XML", "\\data.xml", "Iterations", DataAccessMethod.Sequential)]
[TestMethod]
public void CodedUITestMethod1()
{
    // To generate code for this test, select "Generate Code for 
    // Coded UI Test" from the shortcut menu and select one of 
    // the menu items.
    this.UIMap.AddTwoNumbersParams.TextInput1EditText = 
        TestContext.DataRow["Input1"].ToString();
    this.UIMap.AddTwoNumbersParams.TextInput2EditText = 
        TestContext.DataRow["Input2"].ToString();
    this.UIMap.AddTwoNumbers();

    this.UIMap.AssertforAddExpectedValues.TextAnswerEditText = 
        TestContext.DataRow["ExpectedResult"].ToString();
    this.UIMap.AssertforAdd();
}
```